# How to backup & restore spinnaker pipelines

Tags: azure, backup, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I am new to & trying to use spinnaker for the client I am working with. I am somewhat familiar with spinnaker architecture.

I know `FRONT50` micro-service is responsible for this task. I am not sure how I can safely backup the pipeline data and restore into a new instance.

I want that to be able to continuously back up these pipelines as they are being added so that when I happen to recreate the spinnaker instance(i.e destroy my the infra and then recreate from scratch) I am able to restore these.

I am currently using Azure as the cloud provider and using Azure Container service.

I found this page here : https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/backups/ 
but does not indicate if the pipelines will also be backed up.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure about the standard method but you can copy the configurations for pipelines and applicatons from front50 manually.

For pipelines, just do a curl to `http://<front50-IP>:8080/pipelines`

```
curl http://<front50-IP>:8080/pipelines -o pipelines.json
```

For applications config:

```
curl http://<front50-IP>:8080/v2/applications -o applications.json
```

To push pipeline config to Spinnaker, you can do:

```
cat pipelines.json | curl -d@- -X POST \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header \
    "Accept: /" http://<Front50_URL>:8080/pipelines
```

P.S: My Spinnaker version is `1.8.1` and both, v1 and v2, k8s providers are supported.

Update-2: If you are using AWS S3 or GCS, you can back up the buckets directly.